# How to Check if the user is logged in on reactjs using JWT

Tags: reactjs, cookies, axios, jwt

Im trying to make a system that it can check it the user is logged of not im using reactjs and JWT tokens that can stored to the cookies in browser.

This is my reactjs file code

```
const ApproveRequest = (approveOption) => {
        if (approveOption === "approve"){
            let request = 1;
            axios.put("http://localhost:3001/cash/approverequest",{
                approved: request, 
                id: id,
                header: { accessToken: cookies.getItem("accessToken") },
                withCredentials: true,
            }).then((response) => {
                if(response.data.error) {
                    console.log(response.data.error);
                }else{
                    setCashObject({ ...cashObject, request: request });
                    alert("Request Approve");
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Field to update the request please contact the dev");
        }
    }
```

from my server JWT.js file

```
const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const accessToken = req.header("accessToken");

    if(!accessToken) {
        return res.json({error: "User not authenticated"});
    }

    try{
        const validToken = verify(accessToken, "bluedragon14S");
        if(validToken){
            req.authenticated = true;
            return next;
        }
    }catch (err) {
        return res.json({error: err});
    }
}
```

from server cash.js route

```
router.put("/approverequest", validateToken,async (req, res) => {
    const { request = 1, id } = req.body;
    await Cash.update({request: request}, {where: {id: id} });
    res.json(request);
});
```

I wanted is i want to check if the user is logged in so that he/she can update the request
thank you in advance for your help

Addition in that code i can store the cookies into the browser i just don't know how to check if the user is logged in or not

Answer (score 0):

I think you can access user cookies in this way :

```
req.cookies.accessToken
```

so change this :

```
const accessToken = req.header("accessToken");
```

to this :

```
const accessToken = req.cookies?.accessToken

if(accessToken )
...
```

Comment: it still says user not authenticated

Comment: could you please check if accessToken is set in your browser? 
if using chrome, that's in the application tab

Comment: yes it is stored into my browser

Comment: so, if you use req.headers instead of  req.header will work? I mean this req.headers("accessToken")

Comment: it gives me an error says Uncaught (in promise)

Comment: i think my error is in my frontend not in my server side

Comment: yeap, thats right, please send the header as the third parameter in Axios call 
like this axios.put('example.com',{...},{headers:{ accessToken: cookies.getItem("accessToken") }})

Comment: note :change header to headers

Comment: it says user not authenticated